# knitr execution halted because of http_proxy?

Tags: r, proxy, rstudio, knitr

I had to mess around with my R version to be able to get my secure gateway to connect to R mirrors. I did this by adding `http_proxy=http://servername` to both the properties tab in the R icon, and also by doing:

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy=http://servername)
```

in Rstudio. Could get this to work in R, but not Rstudio. anyway no problem - I can install packages from within R, point RStudio at R and load the package. good.

So I try to create a (default) .Rmd file in Rstudio - when I run knitr, I get the following:

```
Error: 24:17: unexpected '/'
24: http_proxy=http:/
                     ^
Execution halted
```

I can only imagine I am getting this because I messed around setting up the proxy. Would this make sense?

How do I clear/unset any proxy server in Rstudio?

Comment: Have you tried `Sys.unsetenv("http_proxy") ` ?

Comment: just tried in both Rstudio and R. no luck!

Answer (score 1):

Quote the string:

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy = "http://servername")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your on Windows, configure your proxy in IExplorer and use `setInternet2(TRUE)` function in your script to use IExplorer's proxy settings.